# How to extend bash aliases

Tags: bash, grep, alias

How to create an alias that actually extends another alias of the same name in
Bash?

Why:

I used to have `GREP_OPTIONS` set on `.bashrc` to something like this:

```
GREP_OPTIONS="-I --exclude=\*~"
```

I also had a script (let us say, `setup-java.sh`) which I would call before
working on some Java projects. It would contain the line:

```
GREP_OPTIONS="$GREP_OPTIONS --exclude-dir=classes"
```

If I also use Sass, then I would call `setup-sass.sh` which contains the line:

```
GREP_OPTIONS="$GREP_OPTIONS --exclude-dir=\*/.sass-cache"
```

But [`GREP_OPTIONS` was
deprecated](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=411931) and
apparently the standard solution is either create an alias or some script...

Comment: What about bash functions?

Comment: I quite agree -- using a function is a much better option than an alias.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Bash stores the values of aliases in [an array called
`BASH_ALIASES`](https://superuser.com/a/373536/59006):

```
$ alias foo=bar
$ echo ${BASH_ALIASES[foo]}
bar
```

With [parameter
expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)
we can get the either the last set alias (if exists) or the default value:

```
alias grep="${BASH_ALIASES[grep]:-grep} -I --exclude=\*~"
```

Now just do it on `setup-java.sh`:

```
alias grep="${BASH_ALIASES[grep]:-grep} -I --exclude=\*~  --exclude-dir=classes"
```

...and finally on `setup-sass.sh`:

```
alias grep="${BASH_ALIASES[grep]:-grep} -I --exclude=\*~ --exclude-dir=\*/.sass-cache"
```

If the three lines are called, we get what we want:

```
$ echo ${BASH_ALIASES[grep]:-grep}
grep -I --exclude=\*~ -I --exclude=\*~ --exclude-dir=classes -I --exclude=\*~ --exclude-dir=\*/.sass-cache
```

Answer (score 13):

`aliases` chain if you end them with spaces.

```sh
alias print='printf %s\\n ' hey='"hello, fine fellow" '
print hey
```

---

```
hello, fine fellow
```

You can write entire scripts that way, if you're crazy enough. Anyway, if you want to extend an alias, then just make sure the alias you want to extend ends in a space, and tack another on.

```sh
alias grep='printf "%s " -I --exclude=\*~ '    \
      exdir=' --exclude-dir=classes '          \
      exsass='--exclude-dir=\*/.sass-cache '
grep exdir exsass exdir exsass
```

---

```
-I --exclude=*~ --exclude-dir=classes --exclude-dir=*/.sass-cache --exclude-dir=classes --exclude-dir=*/.sass-cache
```

Comment: This is horrifying beautiful.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome.  Didn't know this (and probably won't use it much, because I think it goes against the [Rule of Clarity](http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch01s06.html)) but it is nice to know!  Question, though: Why the space at the start of `exdir`?  (Is that just for alignment for aesthetic reasons?)

Comment: @Wildcard - the latter thing. That Eric S guy always kind of bored me. I do like *When in doubt, use brute force*, though. In my opinion, clarity stems from cleverness. But, yeah, I don't use these either, except for `case` patterns.

Comment: ..."`case` patterns"...?  Example?

Comment: @Wildcard: `fnmatch(){ alias fnmatch='case $1 in '; while "${1:+:}"  2>&-; do eval 'fnmatch pattern list ;; esac'; shift; done; unalias fnmatch; }; alias pattern='${1:+*}) ' list=': do stuff '; fnmatch "$@"`. Doing it with `aliases` allows you to use the patterns' expansions more directly and more safely. You do need a second context w/ `eval` when called from within a function, but it's not inherently unsafe as long as the `pattern` and `list` names are controlled by you. They can only break in most cases even when they're not unless some attacker knowingly correctly ends your `case`.

Comment: I use this *pattern* in my `.bashrc`: `alias sudo='sudo '`, this lets me call all my aliased commands after a `sudo`. Without the space it wouldn't work

Comment: Wow, a lot of nice tricks!

Comment: @Wildcard I feel like interactive aliases that you often use don't have to be 'clear' and easy to understand like scripts and more permanent code does.

Comment: @DylanFrese: "You can write entire scripts that way, if you're crazy enough."  Agreed about interactive use, though.

Comment: @Wildcard - I wasn't exactly advocating such use, but it's true you can, and it's also true you'd have to be at least a little crazy to try.

Comment: @arainone this trick is amazing! I'm setting my alias for sudo (and watch) right now!

Answer (score 2):

A function is a better option than an extendable alias here.

```
grep_options=( )
grep() {
  exec /usr/bin/grep "${grep_options[@]}" ${GREP_OPTIONS} "$@"
}
```

That way, you have two options to add options to the environment:

- Amend the `grep_options` array; this correctly supports options with spaces, literal glob characters, and other corner cases:

  ```
  grep_options+=( --exclude-dir=classes --exclude-dir='*/.sass-cache' )
  ```
- Use the traditional `GREP_OPTIONS` scalar variable, despite its pitfalls (see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) to understand some of these):

  ```
  GREP_OPTIONS+=' --exclude-dir=classes '
  ```

---

That said, if you want your options to be reflected by `grep` instances invoked outside the shell, neither an alias nor a function will do. Instead, you'll want a wrapper script placed earlier in your PATH than the real `grep` command. For instance:

```
# in ~/.bash_profile
[[ -e ~/bin ]] && PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

...and, in `~/bin/grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# load overrides to grep_options on GREP_OPTIONS from local dotfiles
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc

# ...and use them:
exec /usr/bin/grep "${grep_options[@]}" ${GREP_OPTIONS} "$@"
```